# Autopopulate answer fields in Qualtrics with JavaScript not working?

Tags: javascript, html, qualtrics

I've read Qualtric's [tutorial on this](http://www.qualtrics.com/university/researchsuite/developer-tools/custom-programming/example-code-snippets/#ExampleJavaScript)--and they make it seem really easy.
But when I did what the tutorial said, basically opening up the JS editor, copying and pasting "this.setChoiceValue(1, true);" into it (for my multiple choice question), NOTHING happens.

My JS editor for the question looks like this:

```
Qualtrics.SurveyEngine.addOnload(function()
{
    var questionId = this.questionId;
    questionID.setChoiceValue(1, 'text goes here');

});
```

(Actually I want to know how to input answers to Qualtrics question with JavaScript)

So what did I do wrong? Forgive me--I know very little JavaScript

Answer (score 0):

Simple little fix, if you look at the site you linked a bit more closely, you used the snippet for a text entry question, the code for multiple choice is:

```
Qualtrics.SurveyEngine.addOnload(function()
{
    var questionId = this.questionId;
    questionID.setChoiceValue(1, true);

});
```

Comment: I changed my question type to match the JS code for both a multiple choice question and a text entry question...but the expected pre-selection just doesn't happen. I also tried using the simple one liner 'this.setChoiceValue(1, true);' and 'this.setChoiceValue(1, 'text goes here');'--not working either.

Answer (score 0):

It turns out all I had to do to make this work is to change the response type of my multiple choice question from 'single answer' to 'multiple answer'. So instead of looking like this:
[image: single answer multiple choice]

the question should look like this: 
[image]

Then auto-populating the answer choices will work fine, with simply one liners like these in the JS editor:

```
this.setChoiceValue(1,true);//selects Yes in my example question, or 
this.setChoiceValue(2,true);//selects No
```